# jquery: on demand plugin loading fails if alert not present

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using the [jQuery Loader](http://eduardo.pacheco.kanema.com.br/plugin-jquery-load-js-css/) plugin to load files on demand- [tagit](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/tag-it) plugin.

The issue is that if I add an `alert` to the callback function fired on load the plugin loaded seems to work, if I remove the `alert`, the plugin fails.

Any ideas why is this happening?

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
   $("#mytags").Loader(
                {
                    url: [
                        'media/plugins/tagit/css/jquery-ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.custom.css',
                        'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js',
                        'media/plugins/tagit/js/jquery-ui/jquery-ui-1.8.autocomplete.min.js',
                        'media/plugins/tagit/js/tag-it.js'
                    ],
                    success: function(target) {
                        //alert('loaded');                  
                         $(target).tagit({
                            availableTags: ["tag1","tag2", "tag3"],
                            values: ["tag2"]
                        });
                    }
                }
 });
```

Im testing this on my local XAMP environment.

Comment: It seems to be a [heisenbug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unusual_software_bug#Heisenbug) - a bug that disappears when observed. Is it possible to reproduce in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: @rsp: haha.. I love the **heisenbug** term.

Comment: @rsp: It seems like, indeed, it is a heisenbug...http://jsfiddle.net/goliatone/r7MgY/3843/

Comment: @goliatone: Did you try to load all of those resources using `<link>` and `<script>` tags and to run just `$(target).tagit({ ... });` in your script?

Comment: @rsp: Yes, it does work if I include the resources like that.

Comment: @goliatone: Then my guess would be that it's something wrong with the Loader plugin. It's an alpha version after all. Have you  considered using something more popular, like [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/), [Head JS](http://headjs.com/), [LABjs](http://labjs.com/), [ControlJS](http://stevesouders.com/controljs/) or just plain old [jQuery.getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The possible reason why blocking code execution with alert() helps is that, while JavaScript execution stops (including intervals and timeouts), external resources (JS, CSS, images, and xmlhttprequests) may finish loading. But, again, until the code following the alert() completes, none of these external scripts will run and no DOM events will fire.

An example when alert() makes a difference: http://jsfiddle.net/p9Nff/

Comment: I have edited the code I posted. The original code was wrapped inside the `ready` function. I just copied here the meat of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's problaly related with async, do you try to force async to false?

When the alert open the script have time to load your plugins. or it's what Alexey said, your DOM is not ready, put your code into $(function(){ /*code here*/ });

Comment: In theory, the plugin I'm using to manage the lazy loading takes care of the async. But perhaps it does not. Do you know if by adding the alert the code bloc is forced to be executed asynchronously?

Comment: @goliatone by adding an alert you simply block code execution until OK is clicked, it doesn't force it to execute asynchronously. If there is a bug in jQuery Loader, then you should get an error "object has no method tagit". One more random thing to try: wrap that $(target).tagit({}) in setTimeout(function() { ... }, 10). Also check whether $.fn.tagit defined when success() is called.

Comment: @Alexey: In FB's console I have seen the 'object has no method tagit' but inconsistently. The real use case is more complex and other scripts are being loaded. I can rearange my code, and use a different pluging to manage the lazy loading. At this point thou, If you don't mind extending over why blocking code execution might change the behaviour of the plugin in an answer I will mark it as correct.

Comment: @goliatone, updated my answer with a possible explanation, though I doubt it applies to jQuery Loader or Tagit.